# How can I describe how many people are present here or there?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'd had a high school reuion party at Hongdae, but the party was over too early. So, some of us decided to drink more at a park located in Hongdae. At the park, there were a group of girls sitting on a bench, holding a bottle of beer.

> 1. The number of them was 4.
> 2. There were 4 girls.

And, they were mostly pretty, so we decided to go there. But,

> 1. The number of us was 3.
> 2. we were 3 guys.

How can I describe how many people are present here or there?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you guess at a sentence construction that we can tell you if it's ok or not? I don't believe there's any sort of special terminology.

Comment: "There were 4 girls and/but there were 3 of us" - if you wish to describe how many of them there were, and how many of us.

Comment: To extend JMB's reply: You can say "There were four *of them* but only three *of us*."  The "but only" suggests that the 4/3 ratio was something of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There were four girls.
- There were three of us [guys].

(Note that small numbers are generally spelled out.)

Comment: If gender is unimportant or was already specified, the first bullet point could be changed to "There were four of them"